# How to set TemplateDir values for git in Eclipse plug-in?

Tags: eclipse, git, eclipse-plugin, egit

I'm able to set `init.templatedir` as '`C:\UserGit`' in Git Bash and it is working fine.

But I need a same for EGit, i.e when I clone repository from eclipse `templateDir` should be executed.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EGit is based on a Java implementation of Git, called [JGit](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit).

And JGit does not seem to support/implement the [`template_dir` option from a `git init`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init#git-init---templatelttemplatedirectorygt) command: see [this search](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/search?q=template%20init&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93).

Comment: thank you for quick reply, I needed this feature to put hooks in each git repository i clone (or init) in my system, Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: @PrashantHubballi I would use `git` itself to clone / init the repo (and then import it in Eclipse).

Comment: yes I could do that, but an option in Eclipse would have avoided the extra step :)

Comment: @PrashantHubballi I agree, this is only a workaround, unfortunately.